# Android airplane mode API lvl 17 toggle

Tags: android

Since api lvl 17 airplane mode setting was moved from Settings.System to [Settings.Global](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html)

Problem is that now i can't  switch setting anymore. API description is that those settings are read only. Did anyone manage to find a way to change it?

Pre API lvl 17 code that worked:

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 1);
```

API lvl 17 code that I tried and doesn't work :

```
Settings.Global.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, setMode);
```

It throws exception (documentation says it should throw silent log error):

```
11-14 13:39:51.649: E/AndroidRuntime(3509): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

but I have this permission in manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

If anyone knows a way to solve this that would be awesome!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` is a `signature|system` permission, which can only be held by apps that are signed with the firmware's signing key or reside on the system partition. Hence, while you can ask for it, you cannot hold it.

Comment: Thank you on the answer. This problem I was able to bypass by converting my app to system app with an application like Titanium backup. But very few users will be able to do that. It seems there is no simple solution.